# Logging with context information

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, aop, postsharp, serilog

I am working on a greenfield project and I want to integrate serilog with ninject.

The use case is as follows:

- There are a number of common libraries
- These libraries are used in a number of modules i.e plugins. These plugins each receive a GUID at run time which is unique. This
  is a base property on an abstract plugin class which every
  implementation of a plugin inherits
- We want to append this unique name to every log message that a plugin makes 
  as well as any calls to the common libraries from that plugin so that a log 
  message can be traced to the unique instance of a plugin that made it

  - We would prefer not to modify each class in the common libraries to take in a logger to use to log

My thoughts were to :

- Create a singleton logger provider. This will be called by anything needing to log.

  - Use postsharp and CallContext.LogicalSetData to set the GUID prior to any call to the logging provider
  - Use  CallContext.LogicalGetData to get the GUID in the singleton logger provider. This will either retrieve an existing logger for that GUID using Logger.ContextFor or create a new one to add to a dictionary.
  - Use Ninject to resolve the ILoggerProvider to the singleton provider always when requested

Before I down this circuitious route, is there a better way to do this, maybe with ninject?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the solution as described but due to it being a singleton there was no need for ninject in the end.

The solution is working and doesnt seem to have any performance issues logging at high volumes